# OpenSSL tests fail on Windows built with static version of the run-time library using /MT compiler option

Tags: openssl

**I am trying to build OpenSSL 1.1.1f for Windows using:**

- latest Visual Studio 2019 (v16.4.6)
- Strawberry Perl (perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int)
- Windows 10 64-bit

**I am following instructions from** https://stackoverflow.com/a/50365514/220425, basically:

- Download OpenSSL 1.1.1f from official website
- `perl Configure VC-WIN32 no-asm --prefix=C:\some_dir\ --libdir=lib --openssldir=conf`
- in the `openssl-1.1.1e\makefile` I change `/MD` to `/MT`
- in conosle `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019`:

  - nmake
  - nmake test

**Build succeeds, however many tests fail. Here is a fragment from the log:**

```
test\recipes\01-test_abort.t .................... ok
test\recipes\01-test_sanity.t ................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
test\recipes\01-test_symbol_presence.t .......... ok
test\recipes\01-test_test.t ..................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
test\recipes\02-test_errstr.t ................... skipped: This is unsupported on MSYS/MinGW or MSWin32
test\recipes\02-test_internal_ctype.t ........... ok
test\recipes\02-test_lhash.t .................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
test\recipes\02-test_ordinals.t ................. ok
test\recipes\02-test_stack.t .................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
test\recipes\03-test_exdata.t ................... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
test\recipes\03-test_internal_asn1.t ............ ok
test\recipes\03-test_internal_chacha.t .......... ok
test\recipes\03-test_internal_curve448.t ........ ok
test\recipes\03-test_internal_ec.t .............. ok
test\recipes\03-test_internal_mdc2.t ............ Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
```

If I run tests in verbose mode using `nmake test V=1`, more details are revealed:

```
Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/1 subtests
test\recipes\04-test_bio_callback.t .............
1..1
OPENSSL_Uplink(798E0330,08): no OPENSSL_Applink
..\bio_callback_test.exe => 1
not ok 1 - running bio_callback_test
```

**Why the tests fail, and how to fix that?** I need to build OpenSSL with `/MT`

**Notes:**

- If I do not change `/MD` to `/MT` then everything works as expected, and all tests pass
- Building previous versions of OpenSSL works, for example 1.0.1, but starting from 1.1.x they fail

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of getting /MT is to configure 'no-shared', i.e. not
produce DLLs.

https://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg88356.html

Comment: But I needed DLLs with static linking

Comment: You can take difference over makefiles with  'no-shared' argument and without.
There is no runtime library type in CNF_CFLAGS. 
But:
LIB_CFLAGS=... /MT ...
BIN_CFLAGS=... /MT ...